# Maven site generation that shows sites of previous versions

Tags: java, maven, reporting

Maven's site:site functionality gives me access to reports on code and test quality for the current release, but I would like to see the previous releases as well to do comparisons to determine improvements in areas like:

- test coverage
- issues
- code complexity etc
- documentation

without needing to remember it or keep notes.

I assume there's no maven reporting tool that will maintain some sort of state in the SCM between releases, gathering metadata from each report in the pom and storing it to file. That would require every report to make key data available during the build using a standardised mechanism.

One approach I figured would be like how Apache does it with some of their java projects, e.g. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/index.html where the version is built into the site structure.

Comment: A continuous integration server (like jenkins) would do that, assuming you ran site:site as part of the build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating a site, you designate the URL for the project, like the following:

```
<project>
  ...
  <distributionManagement>
    <site>
      <id>www.yourcompany.com</id>
      <url>scp://www.yourcompany.com/www/docs/project/</url>
    </site>
  </distributionManagement>
  ...
</project>
```

If you parameterize the project url to include a unique value in the path (like a timestamp, build number, etc.) the site will be generated using the unique path in each run:

```
<project>
  ...
  <distributionManagement>
    <site>
      <id>www.yourcompany.com</id>
      <url>scp://www.yourcompany.com/www/docs/project/${BUILD_NUMBER}</url>
    </site>
  </distributionManagement>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go for me. It raises the question of how many MBs of documentation does the site contain (currently 10MB) and how often will the build run (roughly once a day). So it looks like this strategy will produce about 1 GB every 3 months or so. Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins which can compare sources with previous releases, like the [clirr-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/clirr-maven-plugin/) and the [jdiff-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jdiff-maven-plugin/). However, what you want is much more complicated. I'd suggest to have a look at [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/), that's the prevert way nowadays.

Comment: SonarQube looks impressive but I am a small fish in a big ocean and the big fish are currently hooked on Fortify.